# Probability using Normal Standard Curve, how to find Random Variables sd?

Tags: probability, random-variables, approximation, standard-deviation, binomial-distribution

My question is relating finding the probability using Normal Approximation.

> Let X be a random variable with P(X=-1)=P(X=0)=0.25 and P(X=1)=0.5. Let S be the sum of 25 independent random variables, each with the same distribution as X.
>
> Calculate 
>      (a)P(S>0)
>      (b)P(S<0)
>      (c)P(S=0)

I know how to do normal approximation, and also have the solutions bank for this question. But I don't know how to find the Standard Deviation. 
Mean is np , hence 25*0.25=6.25. The solutions bank states the standard deviation is 5/4root11. I calculate it as root(25*0.25*0.75) but I know its wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your question saying $P(X=-1)$ twice.

You may have intended $P(X=-1)=P(X=0)=0.25$ and $P(X=1)=0.5$ which would make  $E[X]=\frac14$ and so multiplying by $25$ you get $E[S]=\frac{25}{4}$

If so, $\text{Var}(X) = \frac14(-1-\frac14)^2+\frac14(0-\frac14)^2+\frac12(1-\frac14)^2 =\frac{11}{16}$ and so multiplying by $25$ you get $\text{Var}(S)=\frac{25\times 11}{16}$ the square root of which is $\frac54\sqrt{11}$

Comment: Yep I typed it wrong. It is P(X=1).
Thanks for the answer.